# cant access svn externally

Tags: svn, webserver, centos

yesterday i made a svn repository on mydom.com/b-htdocs. in there is project dir 'one' in which i'll test the folder 'ajax' (cause importing everything takes forever)

I can checkout and import only with file urls:

```
svn co file:///var/www/svn/b-htdocs/one/ajax
```

File works perfectly. but weburls dont work:

```
svn co http://mydom.com/b-htdocs/one/ajax --username root --password pw
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS request for 'http://mydom.com/b-htdocs/one/ajax'
```

its the same with every path on mydom and every username/pw:

```
svn co http://mydom.com/
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS request for 'http://mydom.com'
```

What I actually want to do most of all is version handling with NetBeans. trying to connect to http://www.mydom.com/b-htdocs gives:

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Malformed XML
```

again, username and pw dont seem to matter. trying to connect to http://www.mydom.com/b-htdocs/one or http://www.bonxx.com/b-htdocs/doesnotexits gives:

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
OPTIONS of '/b-htdocs/one': 500 Internal Server Error (http://www.mydom.com)
```

When I try to connect via borwser to http://www.mydom.com/b-htdocs i enter correct username and pw and see:

```
Collection of Repositories
conf/
db/
hooks/
locks/
Powered by Subversion version 1.6.11 (r934486).
```

going to http://www.mydom.com/b-htdocs/conf or http://www.mydom.com/b-htdocs/one or http://www.mydom.com/b-htdocs/doesnotexist gives:

```
<D:error><C:error/><m:human-readable errcode="2">
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
</m:human-readable></D:error>
```

Tortoise SVN throws out errors, too.

How can I solve this access permission problem?

Heres my svn config:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /b-htdocs>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/www/svn/b-htdoc
SVNListParentPath on

# Limit write permission to list of valid users.
#   <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
  # Require SSL connection for password protection.
  # SSLRequireSSL

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion repositories"
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
  Require valid-user
#   </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Server runs CentOS 5.8, I manage via Webmin and i have all administrative privileges. As you can tell I dont know much about SVN, CentOS or webmin. I also dont know if there are securities in place, it's not my server (hopefully nothing). if you need any logs tell me whic and where they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SVNParentPath is **parent dir** for repositories, not repository
2. SVNParentPath must be **outside** webspace, Location of svn-space is **virtual dir**
3. [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic) is your best fiend

Comment: Great! Works! Thanks! all i had to do was change svnparentpath to SVNPath. If only I could give you more upvotes!